# apache mod_rewrite displays object not found 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

I have a link `http://localhost/css/dictionary?letter=a` which I want to make it like this `http://localhost/css/dictionary/a`

but somehow it says 404 message

Am i missing something here? this is my code in .htaccess please help me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /css/


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z])$ dictionary?letter=$1
```

I've been scouring all the youtube videos and reading articles and so far im still in trouble please i need your help.

Comment: Where is this .htaccess file placed?

Comment: in the root directory.. `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]` works fine but the second rule gives me 404 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have 2 rules, and the first one matches first (as it is more general than the second).

The second doesn't even check for `dictionary` at all.

The second condition should be:

```
RewriteRule ^dictionary/([a-zA-Z])$ dictionary.php?letter=$1
```

Comment: how do i combine the two? the first rule supposed to remove the trailing extension.

Comment: @anoldgangstah: I have provided an example.

Comment: the code still gives me 404 error.. the whole day this is my problem dude.

Comment: @anoldgangstah: Try now, I've added the .php extension to the dictionary file in the rewrite.

Comment: oh there it worked for the first time! damn your good! now my problem is it cannot locate the css it looks funny.

Comment: @anoldgangstah: How does the CSS path look like?

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/button.css" type="text/css" media="print">
` this is my links.

Comment: and oh anyway i noticed that when i hover to another links in the page the word dictionary got always included in all links like `http://localhost/css/dictionary/add` instead of `http://localhost/css/add` , how to go about this problem?

Comment: @anoldgangstah: That's a separate question, htacess doesn't generate your links. If the links are relative, try using absolute paths.

Comment: @anoldgangstah: That's because there's no CSS folder in `/a`. You need a `<base>` element, or use absolute paths (better).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15703/discussion-between-anoldgangstah-and-truth)